# Initialize a matrix with specified number of column and rows with zeros in opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have obtained the number of rows and column with the below code.
first i read the image and the size of rows and column are found out.

```
 Mat image;
 int rows=image.rows;
 int columns=image.cols;
```

I want to create a new mat object with zeros having the size of rows and columns.So that i can initialize it.

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Mat new_image= Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_whatever datatype you want);
```